# bash: How to use a quoted argument in select

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, selection

From a command I get some arguments that I want to offer to the user with the select statement from bash in a shell script.  The arguments supplied by the command may contain spaces and are therefore protected by quotes.  Here is a simplified example.

This works as expected:

```
select opt in a b "c d"
do
  echo $opt
  break
done
```

The output is as expected:

```
1) a
2) b
3) c d
#?
```

But with the output from the command in a variable it does not work as expected:

```
opts="a b \"c d\""
select opt in $opts
do
  echo $opt
  break
done
```

Although $opts contains the same as the hard coded typing in the first select-example the output is different:

```
1) a
2) b
3) "c
4) d"
#?
```

So it's not that bash consumed the quotes.  They are kept, but the quotes do not encapsulate an argument as they did when I hard coded them.  As I already wrote I get the arguments as output from a command.  They may contain spaces and are therefore already protected by quotes.  How do I get them in one piece to the 'select' statement?  It is not about single and double quotes.  With single quotes the same happens:

```
1) a
2) b
3) 'c
4) d'
#?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

opts=(a b "c d");

select opt in "${opts[@]}"
   do echo $opt; 
   break; 
done
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thanks.  I'm now working on getting the output from the command in one piece into $opts.  Also there it is split up into array elements at the spaces even between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
opts=("a" "b" "c d");select opt in "${opts[@]}"; do echo $opt; break; done
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  Thanks.  It's the same solution as that from @podwysoc